# linux kernel:why not put device as the first member of platform_device struct

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I just started to learn linux kernel，when read platform device kernel code, i was confused，why not just put device as the first member of platform_device struct,but to use to_platform_device(),shift to the struct start?

```
struct platform_device {
    const char  * name;
    int     id;
    struct device   dev;
    u32     num_resources;
    struct resource * resource;

    const struct platform_device_id *id_entry;

    /* MFD cell pointer */
    struct mfd_cell *mfd_cell;

    /* arch specific additions */
    struct pdev_archdata    archdata;
};

#define to_platform_device(x) container_of((x), struct platform_device, dev)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portability mostly. You don't control the struct definition and it might change in a subsequent version of the linux kernel. And if you depend on the dev being first then the device will suddenly break on an updated version of the kernel.

The container_of is a constant expression, thus it gets calculated at compile time and there's no overhead to this.

Answer (score 1):

From /Documentation/driver-api/driver-model/overview.rst :

> Note also that that struct device dev is not necessarily defined at the
> front of the pci_dev structure.  This is to make people think about what
> they're doing when switching between the bus driver and the global driver,
> and to discourage meaningless and incorrect casts between the two.